# Как объединить две формы?

Tags: javascript, html

Вот у меня была форма. В нее вводят информацию. JavaScript проверяет количество символов и когда все норм, кнопка разблокируется и можно на нее нажать. При нажатии JavaScript выводит формы для добавления 2 файлов. В чем проблема. Как мне объединить эти 2 формы и отправить информацию вместе с книгой методом post. Дать формам одинаковое имя? Ведь javascript не вставляет код, а выводит его. То есть я не могу поставить конец формы после

```
<table id="**"></table></form>
```

Comment: Я думаю, вам слишком рано браться за JavaScript. Начинать надо с малого. Например, изучить базовую грамматику. Выучить некоторые правила набора текста, такие как, например, постановку пробелов после знаков окончания предложения.

Comment: Если у вас нету ответа по теме,лучше уже ничего не писать.Вам не нравится как написан вопрос?Я не имел много времени , чтоб написать со всеми правилами русского языка.

Comment: У вас нет времени написать небольшой абзац правильно, а особенно короткий заголовок из трёх слов, но вы ожидаете, что у других есть время на чтение каракуль и поиск ответа. Я ведь говорю не о каких-то запутанных формулировках правил русского языка, а о самых элементарных вещах вроде как писать "объединение" вместо "обэденение".

Comment: Ну раз вы так считаете!Тема закрыта.Ответ нашел сам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так не делите эти формы, добавляйте в неё поля для файлов если всё остальное введено верно. А ещё лучше, не прячьте поля для файлов вообще, а показывайте их сразу вместе с остальными, а неудовлетворительно заполненные поля подсвечивайте. И не будет никаких проблем тогда с объединением форм.

Comment: Так и сделал)Теперь правда вот думаю как проверит выбран ли файл)

Comment: Проверяйте на сервере + у клиента на пустоту значения в поле файла.